# Как присвоить null календарю в asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть проблема с присвоением календарю значения null. Пишет что null присвоить ему нельзя, пытаюсь конвертировать календарь или как нибудь привести к стрингу, тоже не получается.
Вот как я пытаюсь:

```
cldDateReservCancel.SelectedDate.ToString() = null
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем? Возможно вы пытаетесь решить задачу, которую надо решать совсем другими методами.

Comment: А если `.ToString()` убрать?

Comment: Ни с .ToString(), ни без него работать не будет, вы, в данном случае, "хотите странного".

Comment: ну да, свойство имеет тип `DateTime`, а не `DateTime?`, как, например, в десктопных контролах и как я наивно предполагал. Я, впрочем, не знаток `ASP.NET`

Comment: @Mirdin в зависимости от этой даты у меня делается фильтр, и какая бы дата не была выбрана список будет пустой с ней, мне нужно что бы она осталась нуловой, я конечно могу чек бокс поставить на неё но хотелось решить без него, если нельзя придётся ставит ьчек бокс.

Comment: Добавьте в фильтр, проверку не на нулл, а на какую либо дату, заведомо невозможную.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы не было даты -- не вводите её вообще. Я не понимаю, зачем заставлять пользователя вводить данные, которые потом не будут использоваться.

Comment: @Mirdin записываю вот так вот `cldDateReservCancel.SelectedDate = DateTime.MinValue` не записывается, почему то.

Comment: А что записывается?

Comment: @Mirdin исключение) не идёт туда значение.

Comment: Какое исключение?

Comment: @Mirdin добавил скрин в вопрос.

Comment: Ок, давайте попробуем так, `cldDateReservCancel.SelectedDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);`

Comment: @Андрей у вас в скрине упомянут тип ECalendar. Стоит прямо написать в вопросе - что это за календарь, а то сейчас вы спрашиваете как поменять какое-то свойство в контроле неизвестного никому типа. Точно на такое вам никто не ответит, будут гадать "а в min? а в max? а если потрясти?". Уточните вопрос и напишите точный тип календаря.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedDate` имеет тип `DateTime` и поэтому `null` ему присвоить невозможно. при попытке

```
cldDateReservCancel.SelectedDate.ToString() = null
```

вы пытаетесь присвоить `null` не свойству календаря, а некой анонимной переменной которую вернула функция `ToString()`, такое присвоение, кстати, тоже невозможно, поэтому так тоже не получится.

Вашу задачу надо решать как то иначе, в зависимости от того что это за задача. Воспользоваться сторонним компонентом, например. Или если вам нужно обозначить, например, что дата выбрана не была, можно воспользоваться какой либо датой, которая, заведомо, не может быть выбрана пользователем (например `DataTime.MinData`, если это дата поступления сотрудника на работу) и потом проверять на равенство этой дате.

Answer (score 0):

Для стандартного System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar:

```
cldDateReservCancel.SelectedDates.Clear();
```

У вас, судя по всему, не стандартный - ищите в нем аналогичный метод чистки даты.